# Convert a table data into python tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have below raw_data.

```
'''
Filter_Port table
type                : filter_1
ports               : [7d77a1b7-434b-47fd-b2aa-d3442b831205]

type                : filter_2
ports               : [95a67e8c-63f9-4efc-b6b1-c04d5df61578, e1fea65f-62a3-43e9-8c33-c0e44ac3c86a] 

type                : filter_2
ports               : []
'''
```

I need to convert this as below format using python:

```
result = [(filter_1, ['7d77a1b7-434b-47fd-b2aa-d3442b831205']), (filter_2, ['95a67e8c-63f9-4efc-b6b1-c04d5df61578', 'e1fea65f-62a3-43e9-8c33-c0e44ac3c86a']), (filter_2, [])]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
datastring = '''
    Filter_Port table
    type                : filter_1
    ports               : [7d77a1b7-434b-47fd-b2aa-d3442b831205]

    type                : filter_2
    ports               : [95a67e8c-63f9-4efc-b6b1-c04d5df61578, e1fea65f-62a3-43e9-8c33-c0e44ac3c86a] 

    type                : filter_2
    ports               : []
    '''


output = []
lines = datastring.split("\n")
type_ = None
ports = None
for line in lines:
    if line.strip().startswith("type "):
        type_ = line.split(":")[1].strip()
        assert ports is None, "problem with data"
    elif line.strip().startswith("ports "):
        ports_str = line.split(":")[1].strip("[] ")
        ports = [p.strip() for p in ports_str.split(",")]
        assert type_ is not None, "problem with data"
        output.append((type_, ports))
        type_ = None
        ports = None

print(output)
```

Comment: I just edited my code to add a `.strip()` when testing `line.startswith...`

Comment: Thanks! I just think if we add below two lines .. the we canmake empty list [] instead of [' ']
    `if ports_str:
     ports = [p.strip() for p in ports_str.split(",")]
    else:
       ports = []`